# flutter - make dark / light mode icon change on tap

Tags: flutter, button, themes

I would like to achieve that the icon of my dark / light button changes accordingly when the mode is activated, that is, I would like a sun icon in ligt mode and a moon icon in dark mode. I found different solutions for this, but I can't use them, maybe who can help? It could be that the code is broken down incorrectly because I'm a newbie and I can't get it right: /

```
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Color(0xFF282C39),
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.blue,
                      child: SizedBox(width: 32, height: 32, child: Icon(Icons.brightness_2, size: 20, color: Colors.white)),
                      onTap: () {
                        isDark
                            ? Magazin.of(context)!
                            .setBrightness(Brightness.light)
                            : Magazin.of(context)!
                            .setBrightness(Brightness.dark);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your Icon doesn't change because you set your icon always to `Icons.brightness_2`. You should check if it is using dark/light theme before.

```
Icon(
  isDark ? Icons.brightness_4 : Icons.brightness_2,
  size: 20,
  color: Colors.white,
  ),
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly ;-) .. had it left out because I didn't get the idea for isDark? to try and my code was therefore always buggy, thought before I make my mistakes unnecessarily complicated, I'll take a variant that works and simplifies it. thank you very much for your help 